# "Press enter to exit" does not work

Tags: python-3.x

I have started to read the book Python for absolute beginners (3rd edition) by Michael Dawson. 
And one of the first challenges in the book is to run a programme the author wrote to see what it does. 
That is what it looks like:

```
# Game Over
# Demonstrates the print function

print("Game Over")

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

When I then continue to run the module the following comes up.

">  RESTART: some of my information

Game Over

Press the enter key to exit."

However, when I press enter, the programme does not quit, like he said it would do in the book. He says, the window would disappear, which it does not.

What is wrong with my computer? I have a MacBook, am however using the newest python software from the website.

If you could help me, I would be very grateful, as I am just starting out and am a little wondered what is wrong with my stuff.

Thank you

Comment: Can you tell us how you run the module ? and can you update your question with a picture of what happens after you press enter  ?

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo If I run it via run>run module in the menu bar or via f5 the same happens. it gives me what I wrote above. When I then hit enter the following comes: ">>>" with every tap on enter a new line with those three characters appears. The problem still does not close though.

Answer (score 1):

Answer based on comment of OP:

> When I then hit enter the following comes: ">>>" with every tap on
>   enter a new line with those three characters appears. The problem
>   still does not close though

So, after pressing enter, you see

```
>>>
```

and if you press enter again, you see

```
>>>
>>>
```

The "program" (which is the python script) is actually closed, and you have exited. The `>>>` you see is the python prompt.

To exit the python prompt, type `exit()` and press `enter`

Comment: Ah. ok. Thank you very very much.

Comment: One last question if I may. Why should I use this last statement then? If I don't use it and run the module I directly get to the ">>>" without pressing enter before. Why would I want to press enter to that, if I can get the same result without pressing enter?

Comment: @thebilly I think it would be good for you to search a tutorial for python, one which also explains "command prompts" "python prompt and interpreter". This would be basic fundamental knowledge. Good Luck on you Python adventure

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work
First, install keyboard package using this code

```
pip install keyboard
```

Second, Use this code

```
import keyboard

# Game Over
# Demonstrates the print function

print("Game Over\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("enter"):
        exit(0)
```